# How can I pass data like a variable to a frame in an iframed page

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, iframe, frame

So I have been using this `http://www.facebook.com/connect/prompt_feed.php?api_key=2231777543&message=@[undefined:0:]` Facebook API to make posts to my Facebook. but recently the it doesnt seem to be taking 'message' posts. So I figured I could put that API into an Iframe and pass the data from my form to the form in the API.

I Know I can just type in there but I need to be able to do it this way for my project and any future reference

Comment: If I don't misunderstand you, do you want a Facebook iframe in your page and pass data to it? I guess that's not possible due to the same origin policy.

Comment: Can you give a bit more detail on your program flow? Are you trying to pass information to a tab iFrame or a canvas iFrame?

Comment: well not really I am trying to fill form data for a text area where the text area is located in an iframe

Answer (score 0):

If this is for an iFrame app running on a Facebook page you can pass an app_data field that a backend script can extract that you can use.

Check out this FB blog post:

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/462